# SOCKET INSTALL IN UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: node.js, sockets, npm, npm-install

AM getting this error if i use

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

I used the above to install socket but facing the below errors

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm ERR! Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED

npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:525:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:192:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1462:7)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:111:23)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1367:20)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.CryptoStream._push (tls.js:526:27)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:880:20)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.write (tls.js:267:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.18.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd /home/afreed
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.66
npm ERR! code ESSL
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/afreed/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
afreed@JARVIS:~$ sudo npm install -g n
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/n
npm ERR! Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:525:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:192:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1462:7)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:111:23)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1367:20)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.CryptoStream._push (tls.js:526:27)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:880:20)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.write (tls.js:267:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.18.0-15-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "n"
npm ERR! cwd /home/afreed
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.66
npm ERR! code ESSL
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/afreed/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

or clear cache of your npm:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

or simply you can turn off ssl_cert (**not recommended**):

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```